# Android WebApp storage size

Tags: android, storage

I want to know how many files I can save on the device from my own WebApp. So I need a size and can I save files on the device/sd card?

Thanx
newone

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can store file on disk / sd card from Web application which is running out of URL. You can create an HTML5 database though, which has a limit of 5MB.